# Transparant image as BASE64 disrupted

Tags: php, html, base64, phpmailer

I am adding an image to my `html` like `<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$mail_footer.'"></a>`

`$mail_footer` is the variable that contains the actual code.

The image is shown as:

[image]

I some received e-mail is it shown as:

[image]

Any suggetions of what is happening here and how to prevent this?

Comment: Can you confirm that the base64 data is the same when it shown as black box? Btw, is it necessary to load image as base64 data? why not host it on public server and use actual url as img src?

Comment: The screenshots are from the same email, just some minutes in between.

Comment: Might be an issue with your mail client?

Comment: Are you certain that it is not the surrounding background having become black? The color changing with the image still working sounds like a weird "good luck in bad luck" type of error

Comment: just re-encode the image in JPG format and the problem should go away